# run valgrind for a single file (ignore library)

Tags: warnings, valgrind, suppression

I have a main.c that's using library of 1000's of files

is there a method to ask valgrnd to look for memory leaks only in main.c rather than digging through the library ?

also if valgrind reports an error like this within the library

vex x86->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xC5 0xF8 0x10 0x83
==1796== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x812b234.

is the ability to use valgrind toast ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [suppression file](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) to tell valgrind to ignore errors, including memory leaks.

The instruction `0xC5 0xF8 0x10 0x83` is probably the start of a VEX-encoded instruction such as `vmovups`. You will need a newer version of valgrind with AVX support.